# Reactnative V63+ Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'LinkingManager' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere at code you used = instead of === for platform check. I also faced the same issue.